# Compare multiple JSON responses with JMeter

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter, beanshell

I need to convince JMeter to do an A/B comparison on JSON web service request responses. The challenge I'm facing is that the responses might have the same contents but still not be the same.

Example response1:

`[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Canada",
        "provinceNames": [
            "Alberta",
            "British Columbia"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "United States",
        "provinceNames": [
            "California",
            "New York"
        ]
    }
]`

This response is *fully sorted* "id", "name", "provinceNames" and within the provinceNames, "Alberta", "British Columbia" and respectively "California", "New York" are sorted as well.

Example response2:

`[
    {
        "name": "United States",
        "provinceNames": [
            "New York",
            "California"
        ],
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Canada",
        "provinceNames": [
            "British Columbia",
            "Alberta"
        ],
        "id": 1
    }
]`

This response is not sorted.

The two responses have *equal* contents even though they are not the same.

Has anyone ever had this problem before and has a solution for it?

My approach was to post-process the response, sort the JSON objects, and compare them. Up to now, I couldn't figure out a way neither in javascript nor in beanshell. I found some solutions to similar problems but they use JQuery or other libraries not available in JMeter.

Firstly, I'd like to know whether I'm even on the right track with this approach, or does anyone figured out a much more elegant solution?

Secondly, if this approach is ok, does anyone have any code snippets either in javascript / beanshell I could use in JMeter?

Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: Try searching on `javascript deep compare data structures`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available:

1. Use [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) to extract individual values like name, provinceNames, etc., store them to JMeter Variables and compare the variables
2. Use [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) for the same
3. Use [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to convert JSON response into a sorted string and compare the strings. Example Beanshell code to do it will look like:

   ```
   String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   char [] responseCharArray = response.toCharArray();
   Arrays.sort(responseCharArray);
   response = Arrays.toString(responseCharArray);
   prev.setResponseData(response.getBytes());
   ```

where `prev` is the instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class holding parent sampler result details.

Above code will override original sampler response with original response split into chars, sorted using [Dual-Pivot Quicksort](http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf) and again put back.

If the data is the same in both cases, result string entities will also be the same.

To learn more about enhancing your tests with scripting refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I know there are many articles about this issue, but none of them up to now really solves the problem.

The [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) is excellent if you want to compare specific values but not suitable for entire JSON response comparison.

I am not entirely sure about the 3rd solution but it looks like you are taking the entire JSON as one massive string and sort the characters. That would mean `{"id":"hello"}` would be equal to `{"hello":"id"}` whereas they are very different JSON responses.

Comment: `responses might have the same contents but still not be the same.`. My answer resolves your issue. If you have another question - feel free to ask it in a separate thread.